# Formal definition of limits (operator?)

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

I am still quite new to high level maths and I am interested in how the limit is actually defined. Could it be an operation, like this: $$\lim_{x\to \infty} : f\to\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\ , \ \textrm{with}\ f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m\ \textrm{and}\ x\in\mathbb{R},\ n,m\in\mathbb{N}$$
Thanks in advance for the help :)

Comment: Sometimes the limit does not exist.  So the domain for your operator is not the set of all functions.

Comment: you are right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put: $$\lim_{{\bf x}\to \infty}:\{f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m \mid \exists\,\lim_{{\bf x}\to +\infty}f({\bf x})   \} \to \Bbb R^m \\ f \mapsto \left(\lim_{{\bf x}\to \infty}\right)(f):= \lim_{{\bf x}\to\infty}f({\bf x}),$$ where $\lim_{{\bf x}\to\infty}f({\bf x}) = L$ if: $$\forall\,\epsilon > 0,~\exists\, M > 0\,:\, \|{\bf x}\| > M \implies \|f({\bf x})-L\|<\epsilon.$$

Writing $f$ as the domain of $\lim_{{\bf x}\to \infty}$ is not good - $f$ is the object that you want to apply $\lim_{{\bf x}\to \infty}$ on, not its domain.

Comment: thank you, now I got it :)